Do we have linguists and/or people with general background but interested in Language as a whole?
In my humble and personal opinion, I'd love to see more "academic" questions on the site (also, this is something that the remark about keeping the beta private for another week put).
So not get me wrong, I'm very happy about questions concerning vocabulary, small grammar points, and so on. I'm just saying that I would personally benefit from discussions about fine points where the history of the language plays a role, linguistic style of writing...that is, questions going beyond the simple "is that correct" pattern.
The perfect situation would then be to have a small subset of users that actually have those expertise (linguists would be the best, but even people passioned about Language in general is very good). Do we have this? We could probably attract them when the private beta will go public, but I ask if for the time being we could already think a bit more about this part of the interest in a language.

I think that questions regarding history of language and language's style should surely be on topic.

Despite my classical education in high school, I'm no linguist. I personally like very much learning languages and comparing them, but by no means I can be qualified as an expert.
That being said, I would love to see the site featuring some academic questions on advanced topics concerning the Italian language, something I agree it's not happening so far.
However there's no much we can do in private beta to gather the users we need. If we don't have linguists or experts, we have to wait for them to join us. On the other hand, if we do and they are being "lazy", shame on them!

if you want something like that then we probably need a website only in Italian. Many Italians are just "scared" when someone asks them to write in another language

c'mon, that's a prejudice! Educated people from all over the world, Italy included, are not scared by using English. It may not be a perfect English, but that's our lingua franca.

That was my experience. I saw educated people freaking out because of an English exam or unable to answer a simple question from a tourist. Once I was like that too.
